# Looking for the name of an anime character with spiky red hair and a big red robotic glove

Tags: character-identification, anime, toys

Ok, so a couple years ago (5-6 years), a friend of mine had a toy which resembled a young boy with spicky red hair and a big, red robotic glove. It was from a manga or an anime. Who was he?

Comment: We're going to need more details.  Spikey hair is pretty common in anime.  Anything else you can remember?  I'm assuming a picture is not available, which is unfortunate.

Comment: He was wearing a yellow jacket and if I remember right a white scarf.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add any details you remember.

Comment: Can you ask your friend?  Without more detail, this is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: How big was the toy? Was it a miniature, an action figure, or one of those *giant* models? Did it look like it came with accessories (ie hands shaped to hold, or any other unnatural holes)?

Comment: Is it [Kazuma](http://scryed.wikia.com/wiki/Kazuma_Torisuna) from S-CRY-ed?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like the child or teen version of Hellboy as seen in *Hellboy 2: The Golden Army*.  He had biggish horns (which he ground in adulthood, "to fit in") that might have been mistaken for spikey hair (though his own hair was black, the horns shaded from black to red when long), and his right hand is huge and stony and might easily be mistaken for a robotic glove.  Hi skin is red all over, but he often wears (as an adult) an overcoat in a yellowish color.

[image: Child Hellboy]
[image: Hellboy as an adult]

Comment: Can't get the image -- I'm at work, and at lot of movie and entertainment sites are blocked on the network.  If you can edit one in, I'd be obliged.

Comment: I have the same issue at work (can't even get to a lot of the stack exchange sites).  Google images is allowed, though.